# Mysql to list a Group of row by Scores

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking for MySQL statement to do achieve it.. Any help ?

```
INSERT INTO exam    (`id`, `Names`, `Score`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Ahmed', 55), (2, 'Jacob', 90),(3, 'Rose', 55),
    (4, 'Habib', 90), (5, 'Suhaib', 70), (6, 'Sahil', 70),
    (7, 'Gawai', 55), (8, 'John', 55),(9, 'Pawel', 55),
    (10, 'Bannaga', 70) ;
```

i want result like :

```
   Who Scored 90 :
   +-------------------+
   | Sl   |   id   |   names |
   +----+----+---------+
    |  1.   |    2   |   Jacob
   +----+----+---------
    |  2   |   4    |  Habib
   +----+----+---------
```

similarly for 70 and 55 scores...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: tried but the result is not as expected. I want to display each group in separate line and each name in separate link as mentioned in question

Comment: See the edit in my answer. Please let me know if that is what you are after. Also feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple `SELECT` query with `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT id,Name,Score
FROM exam
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58cb4/3).

A better solution:

```
SELECT Score,GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids, GROUP_CONCAT(Names) as Names
FROM exam
GROUP BY Score
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

The result will be like:

```
SCORE   IDS         NAMES
90      2,4         Jacob,Habib
70      10,6,5      Bannaga,Sahil,Suhaib
55      3,7,8,9,1   Rose,Gawai,John,Pawel,Ahmed
```

See the result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58cb4/4).

**EDIT:**

For the updated question, you can do this:

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS Sl_No,id,Names,Score 
FROM exam
ORDER BY Score DESC, id ASC;
```

Result:

```
SL_NO   ID  NAMES   SCORE
1       2   Jacob   90
2       4   Habib   90
3       10  Bannaga 70
4       6   Sahil   70
5       5   Suhaib  70
6       3   Rose    55
7       7   Gawai   55
8       8   John    55
9       9   Pawel   55
10      1   Ahmed   55
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/205f6/3).

Comment: what's the point of ordering by score when all of the results will have the same score?

Comment: @Robert: See [**this fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58cb4/1) to see the result.

Comment: ah nice.  this is good.  I'm not good at sql so thanks for showing me something I didn't know

Comment: So now I have a question.  If a person was to be using this on a php page, would you have to explode(", ", columnValue) to turn the rows column value into an array? Or how would you go about doing that?

Comment: @Robert: My knowledge in php development is very limited. `GROUP_CONCAT` is the best way for getting such outputs.